# Getting always same value while accessing ui element

Tags: user-interface, background, uwp

I'm developing uwp application. I want to access ui element (toggle switch) from background thread. I created a method where i can get toggle switch status (is it on or off ) And when i try to get value by this method i get always get same value of toggle switch.

My method is as following.

```csharp
public bool GetMoldState
{
    get { return MoldTry.IsOn; }
}
```

And from background thread i access ui element as following.

```csharp
await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
() =>
{
    MainPage  mp = new MainPage();
    isMoldTryOn = mp.GetMoldState;
}
);
```

How can i get current state of toggle switch button correctly?

Comment: Each time you are creating a new instance of MainPage, thus you get the same value. If you want to get a value of your *MainPage* control, you will have to expose it, so that it's accessible from other methods, or better do it via *Binding* and check suitable property.

Comment: actually i tried to create instance once (when background thread starts) and access value but still  same value. How can i expose Mainpage ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of the `MainPage` everytime you try to get the value instead of using the instance created when your app is navigating to the page.

I suggest using `public static` property in the `MainPage` using which you will be able to get values of the actually used instance.

```
public static MainPage Current { get; private set; }

public MainPage()
{
    Current = this;
    // Other things
}
```

Then you will be able to access it's values from anywhere like this:

```
await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
() =>
{
    isMoldTryOn = MainPage.Current.GetMoldState;
}
);
```

Comment: It Works! Thank you so much both of you.